# Image resize with Graphics distorts image on Windows 2003, fine on Window 7

Tags: c#, image, resize

I am trying to resize an image using the following method

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        Image img = Image.FromFile(filename);
        ImageFormat imageFormat = img.RawFormat;

        resizeImage(img, new Size(512, ScaleImage(512, img.Width, img.Height))).Save(@"c:\temp\temp.jpg", imageFormat); ;

    }

    private int ScaleImage(int RequiredSize, int currentSize, int CurrentOpposite)
    {
        return (int)((decimal)RequiredSize / (decimal)currentSize * (decimal)CurrentOpposite);
    }

    private static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {

        int destWidth = size.Width;
        int destHeight = size.Height;

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();

        return (Image)b;
    }
```

On my PC, win7, 8GB ram, bla bla, it works fine. The resultant image is sharp and no issues with it.
If I run this code on the server, w2k3, 16GB ram etc, the resultant image is horrible. It's pixelated and looks like it is compressed to hell and gone.

If I give it an image of about 1024 width, it works ok. Give it something off my phone, 3500 across, and it screws it up.

I'm stumped as to why it would behave so differently on the server. Using the image.getThumbNail does the same.

Comments on a postcard please.

Thanks
Crispin

Comment: Have you tried to specifiy a GraphicsUnit in the call to DrawImage ?

Comment: Any tip and some sample code? I looked and played with it a bit and it looks like it is for drawing shapes? Sorry, a bit of a noob with this.